# Issue with output from For loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to output a message. But I need to make sure that each letter is spaced eg: m e s s a g e, and not message. I also only want alphanumeric characters.

```
for j in message:
    if j.isalnum():
        j = this_dict.get(j)
        output += str(j) + " "
    else:
        pass
    output = output[-1]
return output
```

I need the last part of the message removed so there's no space. But currently, the output is just " ", if I remove the output = output[-1] I get the message as expected but with the space on the end.

I also can't use any libraries or frameworks.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Hint: pay attention to the value of `ouput[-1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "BINGO"
if s.isalnum():
    print(" ".join(s))

>>>>B I N G O
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: please explain how this code solve the problem

Comment: @OMR, Sorry, that was copy paste error from my console. I didn't meant to paste that

Answer (score 1):

just use an easy slicing this will help you get rid of the last text you didn't want

```
newoutput=output[:-1]
return newoutput
```

Comment: Thanks for that I see my mistake now, I'm learning at the moment and haven't had that much exp of working with Python like this!